# InternalError: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block

Tags: python, postgresql, multiprocessing, psycopg2, web.py

I'm getting this error when doing database calls in a sub process using multiprocessing library.

Visit : [Pastie](http://pastie.org/811424)

> InternalError: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until
>   end of transaction block

this is to a Postgre Database, using `psycopg2` driver in `web.py`.

However if I use `threading.Thread` instead of `multiprocessing.Process` I don't get this error.
Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

multiprocessing works (on UNIX systems) by forking the current process. If you have an existing database connection, this will leave the two processes (the current one and the new one) with the same database connection. Trying to use it from both is bad. Create a new database connection in the child process instead.