# Stuck in a django south migration - TransactionManagement error

Tags: python, django, transactions, django-south

I am having a trouble when applying a django south migration:

As always, I executed the migrate command after a successful schemamigration

```
python manage.py migrate webapp
```

The log console:

```
Running migrations for webapp:
 - Migrating forwards to 0020_auto__add_example.
 > webapp:0020_auto__add_example
TransactionManagementError: Transaction managed block ended with pending COMMIT/ROLLBACK
```

The error is not related with the specific migration as if I move backwards and try another it shows the same message.

Edit. This is the log of the query:

```
(0.005) SELECT `south_migrationhistory`.`id`, `south_migrationhistory`.`app_name`, `south_migrationhistory`.`migration`, `south_migrationhistory`.`applied` FROM `south_migrationhistory` WHERE `south_migrationhistory`.`applied` IS NOT NULL ORDER BY `south_migrationhistory`.`applied` ASC; args=()
Running migrations for webapp:
 - Migrating forwards to 0020_auto__add_example.
 > webapp:0020_auto__add_example
(0.002) CREATE TABLE ROLLBACK_TEST (X INT); args=()
TransactionManagementError: Transaction managed block ended with pending COMMIT/ROLLBACK
```

Comment: Can you enable sql logging and attach the results here?  https://coderwall.com/p/uzhyca

Comment: Thanks tuxcanfly. At least I learned how to log the database when executing django queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am writing the answer to the problem I had as it can be useful for somebody.

After some time of debugging I found that the problem was not related with django. It was an issue with the database and the virtual machine that hosts it.

I restarted the database machine and the migrations are now working.

Answer (score 15):

I just ran into a similar issue.

- MySQL 5.6.13 (on Amazon RDS)
- Django==1.5.4
- MySQL-python==1.2.4
- South==0.8.2

I went through almost every possible fix here and through countless Google searches with zero luck.

I looked at the database schema and a table I had not created named 'ROLLBACK_TEST' was part of the schema.

Once I dropped that mystery table the migration ran flawlessly.

This table could only have originated via Django, South or possibly an internal process at Amazon as nothing else has access.

Comment: I ran into the same issue. I aborted a migration and ROLLBACK_TEST was a table left in the database. Dropping that table told South things are ok.

Comment: Note that you may run into this issue if your DB user doesn't have drop privileges

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem with Django 1.6 and South 1.0 on a MySQL instance. After turning on the django.db.backends logger I realised the migration was stuck on the following SQL statement:

```
DEBUG (0.003) CREATE TABLE ROLLBACK_TEST (X INT); args=None
```

So I checked the database and sure enough found the ROLLBACK_TEST table. Deleting it resolved the problem:

```
$ manage.py dbshell
mysql> DROP TABLE ROLLBACK_TEST;
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and was banging my head for a while.
It turns out my (MySQL) database user didn't have sufficient privileges.
I assigned: ALTER, CREATE, DELETE, DROP, INDEX, INSERT, SELECT, UPDATE to the user and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and for me the solution was simply to give the proper rights of my sqlite `development.db` file to the user who was executing the `python manage.py migrate webapp` command. I had the file owned by `www-data` and hence couldn't work on the file.

Answer (score 0):

When I came to the same issue my problem was more or less related to django. I explain.

I was working with different tabs in my console. One was used with a django shell to test my models and in another tab I run the migrations. I came to an integrity error in my shell tab. So, until I solved the problem ([see this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7753016/djangopostgres-current-transaction-is-aborted-commands-ignored-until-end-of)) or closed the tab, the error in migration tab persisted. As the former answer pointed out, this was something related to the DB -but not DB's fault.